# Upgrading from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, partial-upgrade

I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04, and when I first tried according to the release notes, only a part of the installation was completed and it was cancelled. Now if I try to repeat the same steps, then a message comes saying that "do either partial update or complete" when I try to do a partial update after completing the others, then it asks for the password. When I enter the password, then the window disappears and nothing happens. 
Please help.

Comment: Run the upgrade from the commandline (`sudo apt do-release-upgrade -d`).  Address any error messages you get with the resolution provided on the terminal screen.  Post the exact error output to your question if you get stuck.